# What's the name given to the ratio $P^2/A$ for a closed figure in the Euclidean plane?

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of all plane, closed Euclidean figures having positive perimeter, and let $\sim$ be the [similarity relation on $\mathscr{F}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29).

Then, for any equivalence class $\widetilde{F} \in \mathscr{F}/
\sim$, the ratio $P^2/A$, where $P$ stands for the perimeter and $A$ for the area, is invariant over $\widetilde{F}$.

Does this ratio $P^2/A$ have a standard name?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For example, when $\widetilde{F}$ is the class of all squares this ratio is $16$, and when $\widetilde{F}$ is the class of all circles, it is $4 \pi$.  The *isoperimetric inequality theorem* asserts that (1) the latter value is in fact a lower bound for the ratio, as $\widetilde{F}$ ranges over $\mathscr{F}/\sim$; and (2) it is not attained by any other equivalence class in $\mathscr{F}/\sim$.  On the other hand, it's not hard to see that this ratio has no upper bound.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Encyclopedia of Math](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isoperimetric_inequality,_classical) calls it *isoperimetric ratio*, and Google finds quite a few articles using that phrase for it.